# wall of rock/rocks

Tags: grammar

In *Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets* by JK Rowling, Lockhart casting a curse has caused the explosion of the wand and they were inside a tunnel. After that a rock wall formed between Harry and Ron.

> Next moment, he was standing alone, gazing at a solid wall of broken rock.
> "I'm here!" came Ron's muffled voice from behind the rockfall.
> "I'll try and shift some of this rock."

Why '*rock*' has been used instead of *rocks* as they are great chunks of ceiling rocks?
I can't see any difference.

Answer (score 1):

It’s like a :

> a wall of glass

or

> a wall of steel

or

> a wall of sound.

It’s referring to the type of material therein.

Comment: But what about "I'll shift some of this rocks/rock"? I find no difference.

Comment: “Some of this rock” or “Some of these rocks” ... These 2 variants both ok. But “some of this rocks” is not ok.

Comment: _Rocks_ (objects) = _pieces of rock_ (substance).